# Не загружается профиль Outlook у разных пользователей на разных серверах

Tags: email, outlook, exchange

Всем привет!
Вчера примерно с 16 до 19 не загружались профили Outlook у разных пользователей на разных серверах, если создавать новый профиль, то он тоже не загружается. Ошибок не было, само началось и само закончилось. Что проверить, чтобы найти из-за чего возникли трудности с доступом?

Comment: наверное логи и системные журналы на серверах почты